# Prove by induction: the string $\forall x f(x,c)$ is not an $S-$term (where $S$ is an arbitrary symbol set). Do we really need induction?

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic

I got this question in the lecture notes

> Prove by induction: the string $\forall x f(x,c)$ is not an $S-$term (where $S$ is an arbitrary symbol set).

Well, as far as my readings are concerned I know that something is a term over a language $\mathcal{L}$ if it is one of the following

1. A variable
2. A Constant
3. Complex form: $f t_1 \cdots t_n$ where $f$ is a function of arity $n$ and $t_i$ are terms.

Well, looking at $\forall x f(x,c)$ I can say exactly that it is not any of the three cases, hence it is not a term. Where do we need induction?

Answer (score 1):

An excessively formal reasoning could sound like the following one:

The string $\forall xf(x,c)$ contains $\forall$. We'll prove using induction on length that it's impossible for terms. Since no variables nor constants contain quantifiers, we get the base. The step is: since $\forall$ is not a functional symbol and any term of length $>1$ is obtained by concatenation of a functional symbol and a few shorter terms, we conclude that this string is not a term.

I am not sure that it is what was intended but see no other explanations.